# error linking ffmpeg library

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg

While linking `libavcodec.a` , I see these errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(fft_mmx.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `ff_cos_32' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
```

Note: ffmpeg was configured with `--enable-pic option`

My system is ubuntu 11.04 64 bit.

Any pointers regarding this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You're linking 64-bit code against 32-bit code. Use the same arch when building all the object files.